# Git: Are pushed changes of a file present in a remote repos .gitignore file accepted?

Tags: git, github

I want to track a file locally by removing it from .gitignore, so that this file can be edited locally in various branches for my own testing purposes. However, I know that the remote repository has this file in .gitignore and it should stay this way. What will happen if i push changes to the repository of a file in the repositories .gitignore? Will the repository accept these pushes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. A remote repository will accept commits, even if they change or add files that are in the remote repo's .gitignore file.

The .gitignore file is powerful, but it only does certain things. For instance, if a file isn't part of the repository and the ignore list says to ignore it, then that file doesn't show up when you run `git status`. If you run `git add -A` then the ignored file doesn't get added to the repo, even though `-A` means "add all files". And if you try to add the file directly with `git add your-ignored-file`, then you'll get a warning message and the file won't be added.

```
$ git add your-ignored-file

The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
your-ignored-file
Use -f if you really want to add them.
```

But putting a filename in the .gitignore file *doesn't* actually mean that the file can't be part of the repository. Even if you haven't changed the local .gitignore file, you can get your ignored file into the respository using `git add -f your-ignored-file`. And .gitignore won't have any effect on whether you can upload commits to the remote repository.

So the answer is yes. If you edit your local versions of those files, *and* if you commit those edits to your local branch, *and* if you push your local branch to the remote branch, then the remote branch will include those files.

So the key is that you need to avoid doing one of those things. You can make any edits you want to your local files, but if you don't commit the edits, then it won't have any effect on the remote repo. Or you can commit the changes to a local branch, you just have to make sure you don't push those branches to the remote repo.

The .gitignore file is just a file, like any other, so it can contain different things in different branches. I'd recommend you can keep it unchanged in the 'main' branches (the ones you've pulled from the remote) and then have an edited version in your own local testing branches.

One question though: why is it important not to upload the changes to the remote repository? Most projects will let you upload your own personal testing branches to the remote repo. That lets you share your work or take advantage of things like CI on Gitlab or GitHub. If you only make changes to your own personal local branches, and then you push those changes, they'll end up as named personal branches on the remote repository. Your branches shouldn't have any effect on other people's branches.

Comment: Thanks this comment really cleared up what my various options are. You're right, pushing to the remote repository, wouldn't be a big deal as long as the changes aren't pushed to the master branch. I'm relatively new with Git and have been a bit overly cautious when it comes to pushing my own commits i suppose. But thanks again for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

The `git push` command doesn't push *files*.  What `git push` pushes are *commits*.

It's true that commits *contain* files (snapshots).  But it's a package deal: you either send the commit—which sends *all* those files—or you don't.

If you have commits that contain the file that the other guy is attempting to keep *out* of his commits, don't send him those commits.  There is no easy road here: if you *make* those commits, you must be very careful with them, because Git commits spread like viruses.  Git is designed to give out commits to everyone.  When two Git repositories have Git-sex with each other, the receiver's usual default is to pick up everything it can from the sender.  (You, as the sender running `git push`, *can* be careful about what you send, but you *must* be careful.)

Answer (score 0):

When working locally and you want to ignore a file, you can add them to the `.git/info/exclude` file. The files would not be pushed to your remote repositories.

For the `.gitignore` file, all the files that would be ignored by everyone who is working with files in this repository. so add to the `.git/info/exclude` for files you use personally and no one else.

You could use the `git stash` command which takes your uncommited changes, both staged and unstaged, an saves them away for later use, and then reverts them from your working copy.

Comment: This isn't right.  It's not exactly *wrong* either but it doesn't do what the OP wants.